# Hazelcast:how to detect network failure while getting cache from map

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

There are two nodes in hazelcast cluster. i am trying to get cache from map which may be store on second node.In case of network failure it will go into wait loop while getting cache from map.
Is there any way to detect immediate network failure while getting cache from map instead of waiting .
I have tried tryLock  before calling get ,which return immediate true or false but not sure it will work in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

What `IMap.tryLock` does is to invoke a LockOperation with *0 timeout*, so that if there is a network partition it will return right away. 
You can achieve similar scenario using `IMap.getAsync(key)` which returns `ICompletableFuture` object. 
Then use `ICompletableFuture.get(timeout, timeUnit)` to set a timeout for getting entry from map.

Network partitions are detected via heartbeats. When a member doesn't send heartbeats for a certain timeout, it is considered dead. So there is no immediate way to detect network partitions but you can configure the behavior via `hazelcast.heartbeat.interval.seconds` and `hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds` properties. (see [System Properties](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.6/manual/html-single/index.html#system-properties) in Hazelcast Docs)